# Is it possible to implement deep linking for telegram bot longpolling version?

Tags: telegram-bot, deep-linking

Telegram API allow to implement deep linking mechanism (https://core.telegram.org/bots#deep-linking). Telegram webhook version is difficult to test locally. So is it possible to implement this mechanism in long polling version?

Comment: Use `ngrok` for testing webhook locally. You'll need to setup webhook on deep linking too.

Comment: Yes, You can :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed possible: Telegram Bot works with either **Polling** or **Webhook**, it is up to developer to decide which one fits best.
Typically the webhook is more efficient (hence recommended) as the updates are pushed from Telegram to the Chatbot.

I use the following strategy:

- on my local development I use `polling`: you can indeed use `ngrok` to expose the webhook but polling is a lot simpler
- on production (after deploy to a cloud hosting) I use the webhook approach (for the advantages explained above).

See an example here on one of my [GitHub projects](https://github.com/gcatanese/SampleTelegramQuiz)